# Calculus (value of $c$)

Tags: calculus

The slope of the tangent line to the graph of

$4x^2+cx-2e^y=-2$

at $x=0$ is $4$. Give the value of $c$.

What I'm confused about here is the 3 variables. Is it implicit differentiation or something?

Comment: Yes, implicit differentiation is the way to go. We have that $y$ is implicitly a function of $x$. However, $c$ is a constant that you need to determine, not a function of $x$ or $y$.

Comment: "the 3 variables":  There are only two variable here: $x$ and $y$.  $c$ and $e$ are constants.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use implicit differentiation.

Therefore, taking the derivative

$$8x + c -2e^yy' = 0$$

When $x =0$, $y' =4$

Also, finding the value of $y$

$$0 + 0 -2e^y = -2$$

So, $y = 0$

Substituting this into our equation for the derivative:
$$0 + c - 2*e^0*4= 0$$
$$0 + c - 2*1*4= 0$$

$$c = 8$$
Thus, $c= 8$

Comment: I don't get why you added $y'$ right next to $-2e^y$. I know you took the derivative.

Comment: Because we are differentiating with respect with x, in order to take the derivative of the variable $y$ in terms of $x$, we must represent it as $\frac{dy}{dx}$, or in short hand, $y'$. take a look at this: http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der05/der05.html

Comment: He differentiated with respect to $x$. Since that term has a $y$ being differentiated, you multiply the derivative by $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $y'$.

Comment: I understand. I was taught with $dy/dx$ so i got confused.

Comment: @Hello sorry for the confusion. It easier for me to write it in short hand notation :).

Comment: Where did the $y$ go?

Comment: @Hello in which part?

Comment: in the last part. wait you just edited it, let me look

Comment: I substituted the value of y that I found, $0$, into the equation that is the derivative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16764/discussion-between-hello-and-varun-iyer).

Comment: Why did you plug 0 into the original?

Comment: I needed to find the value of $y$ when $x$ was 0. This is because when I find the derivative I need a value for y to plus into the equation.

Comment: why when x = 0?

Comment: That is the condition you gave.

Comment: Yeah but it said the slope of the tangent line at x=0 not the original (I know you're right I'm just confused)

Comment: When $x = 0$ what is $y$? That is what I'm trying to figure out here. You gave me one of the other values when $x = 0$, which was the slope.

Answer (score 1):

For sure, implicit differentiation is the shortest way to go.

Otherwise, from $$4x^2+cx-2e^y=-2$$ you could extract $$y=\log \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(4 x^2+cx+2\right)\right)=\log\frac{1}{2}+\log(4 x^2+cx+2)$$ from which $$y'=\frac{8 x+c}{4 x^2+cx+2}$$ So, for $x=0$, the slope is just $\frac{c}{2}$ and you want it to be equal to $4$